# Select row with the name of an operator php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

While working on my project i have discovered the following problem.

I have a row named:

> "desc"

The problem is that this is the name of an SQL operator.. so i can't select it or use it in SQL statements. I tried using

```
  SELECT 'desc' FROM table WHERE  ....
```

in statements.. but is does not work. Can you please help me out?

Ps. I can't change the name of the column while it is used in way too many places already :(

Comment: DONT use the reserved words http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html or MySQL data type names..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ``` backticks(``) ```

```
SELECT `desc` FROM table WHERE
```

Comment: yea...how can i type those on an wireless apple keyboard? :)  Ps. next to shift i have "~" :|

Comment: don't you have layouts like in windows

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69820/typing-a-backtick-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard

Comment: DONT advise backticks to hack so you can use the reserved words http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html or MySQL data type names.. if Oracle remove the backticks you will hang..

Comment: @royal ... i have read that before asking...but bec. i am used to press that button while holding shift... i forgot that it can be pressed without holding another key :). My mistake

Comment: @RaymondNijland i know about that....but i just can't change the row's name (it is used in a lot of functions).

Comment: @RaymondNijland it's not a hack, it's the official syntax of queriyng a MySQL db - using backticks around column and table names.

Comment: True but it isn't ANSI SQL standaard so you can never port your tables to PostgreSQL and the backticks are causes of confusions..

Comment: @RaymondNijland seriosly, man? It's easier to replace all backticks to double quotes or remove them, than to change queries which has `DATE_SUB` with `INTERVAL` to work from MySQL to PostgreSQL, or even a simple query which has `ORDER BY RAND()` ...

Comment: True but you get very nice readable SQL like these  ORDER BY `desc` desc,  ORDER BY `desc` asc, GROUP BY `desc` desc, GROUP BY `desc` asc, that was the point in this question you are causing confusion now if somebody doesnt know the backtick..

Comment: @RaymondNijland If someone doesn't know the backtick, he may need to go back to MySQL beginning tutorials :) Most of the major MySQL clients (phpMyAdmin in that case) structures their queries which you are making via the GUI with backticks. If you are involved into a project where a column name is named `desc` you'd better do your best to use it as `desc` instead of changing it and slow down the work of you co-workers to edit billions of queries. If you want to involve more readibility you can use aliases SELECT `desc` as 'description' FROM ... ORDER BY description ASC

Comment: Still i see we have different point of views still.. mine opinion you should not create tables or columns that use some keywords of SQL or MySQL SQL dialect and you should create self explaining columns names.. desc as column name also could mean description or descending or ....  so you need to look at the documentation or data to find that out..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I also think you must not name the columns this way, but my comments were referring your comment where we should not suggest `hacks` (which are MySQL standard). So, if you are the one who plans how the db/table names should be done - OK. But when you are in an existent project, which has millions of line code, to come and say `Guys, I'm changing the column name, because it's wrong to have this name and you need to change your queries accordingly` is immature approach.

Comment: Ok indeed i've should not had used the word hack for the backtick feature within MySQL.. well if you use an ORM or Mapping code it can be changed easly... but handrewriten querys is indeed an no go because it is dumb copy paste work and you may introduce bugs...

Comment: @RoyalBg i do not usually use column names that can be used as operators...but this is a project i have taken from another programmer who got himself fired...and i could not change the column name without messing out the rest of the files... :|